# Can't add filter on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug

I've been trying to add a filter on Stack Overflow today. Every time I try to save the filter, I can see this error in the developer console:

> GET https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/filters/edit/filter_id 500 (Internal Server Error)

I cleared all cookies and site data, logged in and out, and tried different browsers. Is there something wrong with the site, or is my account somehow borked?

> Google Chrome    48.0.2564.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
> Revision    700a0e589ecfa7e0f65cace17e2f75470c4adf9d-refs/branch-heads/2564@{#706}
> OS    Mac OS X
> Blink    537.36 (@700a0e589ecfa7e0f65cace17e2f75470c4adf9d)
> JavaScript    V8 4.8.271.20
> Flash    20.0.0.306
> User Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36

Comment: This is the [general SE question filter](//stackexchange.com/filters), right? I can't repro, but I'm using Pale Moon.

Comment: Hi Nathan, that's correct. I'll try again!

Comment: To closevoters: please do not be trigger happy at the words "Stack Overflow". This is a network-wide question, and **legit here**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to have been resolved.